# I have been asked to change the review I gave to a paper

Tags: peer-review

I rejected a paper after careful review and consideration, writing six pages to justify my decision.
In less than 24 h I have received a petition to change my verdict to major changes. The rationale is that the other two reviewers have given major changes and that my review is too harsh and not well enough substantiated.

- Is this normal?
- Is this ethical?
- Any further thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: The other reviews certainly shouldn't be a reason for you to change your review. However, "too harsh and not good enough substantiated" -- this is perfectly possible, and the objection would then be normal and ethical.

Comment: You were asked by whom?

Comment: The idea that a persons opinion should change due to a majority disagreeing is, in my opinion, not normal.

Comment: Not normal... the editor could just override the decision of any reviewer's. Is this one of those open review journals that everyone can see the reviews?

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to why it matters. Generally speaking, with the journals I'm familiar with the reviewer's recommendation (reject/major changes/minor changes/publish as-is) is just that - a recommendation. The Editor has final say. (I don't know if this journal's policies are different, here.) -- In many cases the reject/revise recommendation is a separate private communication to the editor, never seen by the authors. ... Is that perhaps what the editor is asking? For you to remove any mention of  "recommend reject" from the comments which will be sent to the authors?

Comment: @Parrotmaster `The idea that a persons opinion should change due to a majority disagreeing is, in my opinion, not normal.` Being given feedback and being asked to reconsider an opinion in light of it is quite normal. I don't understand why so many answers seem to think ignoring the reviewer is OK, but asking the reviewer to reconsider is not OK. It seems the latter is strictly more respectful towards the reviewer.

Comment: What field and community are you in?  What is normal depends on the field.  Different fields have different reviewing practices.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86758/conflict-with-conference-program-committee

Comment: What's meant by a "petition"?

Comment: @Thomas Being asked to reconsider and what I said aren't related.

Comment: @witizer can you give any details of the review system? Which publisher? Do you have access to the other reviews to inform yourself of the disparity?

Comment: Is the journal pay-for-publish "open access"? They tend to misunderstand the peer-review process (the decision to reject is up to the editor, not the reviewers) and also have a strong monetary incentive to publish all papers regardless of the quality.

Comment: It happened to me once.  I suspected that the co-authors hadn't actually read the paper (besides a lot of grammar mistakes, and the co-authors being native english speakers while the author wasn't), it didn't relate the work to that of the co-authors to say how it was different .... and it didn't cite any of their work, only the author's.  The editor wanted 'major changes'.

Comment: I wonder if this is in some academic field in which editors must transmit all reviews to the author. Why can't the editor just send the other reviewers' comments to the author and withhold yours if the editor disagrees with them?

Comment: I think it would help if you reproduced the wording of the request. There's a difference between "Would you consider revising your opinion?" to which you can reply "after considerable thought, no". Versus: "Please revise your opinion," which is not the same thing. Although you'd want to consider whether the person writing to you is a native speaker, before jumping to conclusions. If they ask you to change your verdict, don't. If they ask you if you would consider changing it, think about it and then accept/refuse.

Comment: ...the eidtor can simply disregard your review if they deem it is inappropriate. What you are describing makes no sense whatsoever. Are you sure that this is a real journal and not a predatory one?

Comment: Is there a real cost of a new paper being written compared to the current paper being rewritten?

Answer (score 95):

I have written quite a few reviews, with a significant percentage of them recommending rejection. Editors often made the decision to reject; sometimes they deviated and asked for major corrections. This is normal — editors have to take reviews into consideration, but are not bound by them. Not a single time have I received a request to change a review.

- *Is this normal?*

**No**, this is not normal, in my opinion. There is no good reason for the editor to ask you to change the review. If the editor believes the paper deserves a major correction, they simply have to make their decision, noting your recommendation.

- *Is this ethical?*

**No.** Under no circumstances should an editor disclose the recommendation of other reviewers to you to ask you to amend your recommendation to join the majority. You were asked to express your own opinion, which you did. The editor is trying to receive an unequivocal agreement, which is not necessary and not fair to you. The editor does not have to follow your recommendation, but they have to respect it.

- *Any further thoughts?*

Please make the name of the journal known. I would refrain from ever using the journal(s) which allow such reviewing process to take place.

Comment: While in general I agree that you should never be asked to change your review, one slight sublty is systems like the one they use a eLife. Here, once all the reviews are received, the reviewers have a teleconference, chaired by the editor, and a consensus decision is reached.The authors then receive a single review that is the consensus opinion of the reviewers. If revisions are recommended, then the authors receive a single set of recommendations. All reviews are and correspondence is made public with the paper on publication.

Comment: +1 in general, but I'm not sure I agree about making the name of the journal known here.  If it's a respectable journal, the issue is likely with the editor and maybe the appropriate thing to do would be to discuss this privately with the editor-in-chief.

Comment: `Under no circumstances should an editor disclose the recommendation of other reviewers to you` That is simply false, at least in my field. Reviewers are often expected to discuss the paper and reach consensus. In particular, if one reviewer has a concern, the others are asked to comment on it. In my field, it is _expected_ that you will edit your review after conferring with other reviewers.

Comment: I moved the extended discussions in comments as well as the debate on interpreting the question [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86118/) and only left the main objections here. Please only post further comments if you can reasonably expect that they will lead to the answer being improved. Also see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/7734).

Comment: The last paragraph of this answer advises escalating the situation. That is very likely to be bad advice. Please either remove it or qualify it (i.e., "be sure you are not misinterpreting the editor's intent"). Also there are other, less drastic, options that can be suggested, such as writing back to ask for clarification of the petition, or contacting the editor in chief.

Comment: @Thomas : Writing "in my field" might be more useful and more comprehensible if you said what field that is.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Computer science, but that doesn't matter. This answer makes an unqualified general assertion that is simply not universally true.

Answer (score 65):

In my experience, the decision whether to reject an article or request major changes is up to the editor. You, as reviewer, give input on this but the editor has to take the final responsibility. In particular, this means that you don't have to change your verdict for the paper to be given major changes.

Comment: +1 Simple and clear. If they do not like your verdict, the editor can override your suggestion. To ask you to change the review makes only sense if it is insulting or offensive, or grossly and factually wrong.

Answer (score 30):

This isn't normal. The process I'm familiar with is to simply forward the reject review to the authors along with a letter by the editor saying that "we find your paper acceptable if the reviewers' comments are addressed" etc.

I'd tell the editor your comments are what they are, and he/she doesn't have to follow your recommendation. You might also want to check if they're a predatory journal. I'd probably do the same thing if they are predatory, but it'd still be a good thing to know.

Comment: Playing devils advocate: if OP was totally wrong in their assessment, and other reviewers were well respected and gave sound endorsements for the paper (I've certainly seen that a few times...), a proactive editor might reasonably point out the inconsistency and ask the outlier to reconsider.

Comment: But can't that editor simply ignore the hypothetically inconsistent review and proceed how they wish to proceed? Why bother asking the reviewer to change?

Comment: @beldaz, exactly: "ask to reconsider".  Not "please change your verdict to 'recommend major changes'".

Comment: @Mark agreed - directing someone to give a specific verdict does not sound appropriate

Comment: @beldaz But what does the editor gain if OP reconsiders?

Comment: @sgf sometimes if a review is an outlier it can be due to a misunderstanding. If the review takes the opportunity to reconsider and decides they are in agreement with the other reviewers, a consistent verdict is reached and the editor can be satisfied that the final decision on whether to accept a paper is based on sound opinions. But as Mark points out, directing a specific verdict, as appears to be the case here, would not be appropriate.

Comment: @sgf the implication of this is that the paper isn't up to scratch but the editor wants to accept it anyway. The editor gains by having an extra paper to publish (this is especially the case for smaller journals that struggle to fill their issues).

Comment: @Allure But the editor doesn't need the reviewer's approval to accept the paper, so what does he gain from making the reviewer reconsider?

Comment: @sgf that would present a united front - it makes the decision seem more unanimous instead of the editor rejecting a "reject" review.

Comment: @Allure ... which benefits the editor how?

Comment: @sgf you've already asked that question and I answered it above ... ?

Comment: @Allure No, you haven't told us how the editor benefits from a unanimous decision. Your answer above was that the editor gains by having an extra paper to publish, but that's also true if he just accepts it without changing OP's mind first.

Comment: @sgf that would present a united front - it makes the decision seem more unanimous instead of the editor rejecting a "reject" review.

Answer (score 25):

You should change your review if and only if you are honestly convinced that your original review was wrong.

As a reviewer, I have no objection to being overruled by the editor --- even if he accepts without changes a paper that I said should be rejected (or vice versa). That is his right as editor.  I would, however, object very strongly to a request to submit a review that does not represent my honest assessment of the paper. In my opinion, it is unethical for an editor to make such a request, and it would be unethical for me to comply with it.

(In your situation, I would also feel somewhat insulted that a six-page report is considered insufficient substantiation.)

Comment: Re “…insulted that a six-page report is sufficient substantiation”: longer doesn’t necessarily mean better.   For my part, I have to admit that a couple of the longest referee reports I’ve written are ones where I got annoyed about some shoddiness or other scientific irresponsiblities in the submission, and got a bit too emotionally engaged in documenting the problems carefully — so, while I do stand by those reports, I could imagine an editor reasonably asking me to reconsider whether I was being overly harsh.  (Of course, the editor must be ready to take “no, I stand by them” as an answer.)

Answer (score 18):

> - Any further thoughts?

1. I recommend giving yourself a minimum of 24 hours before you send back a reply. This will make sure you don’t do anything rash or allow emotional issues to dictate your actions.
2. Just in case you’re one of those people who have a hard time saying “no”, especially to requests coming from figures of authority, it’s good to remind yourself (multiple times if necessary) that **you are not required to comply with the request**.
3. Regarding the ethics question, others have addressed this, but I think it’s worth sharpening the ethical lines here a bit. If the request is simply that you *reconsider your position* (since it is perceived as too harsh by the editor and other reviewers), I think that’s an unusual request but not an unethical one. It is fine (if usually futile) for either the author or the editor to push back and ask you if you might revise your position based on new arguments or because they believe you haven’t given the matter sufficient consideration (which sounds unlikely in this case, but I suppose it’s theoretically possible). The point is that in that case they are asking you to actually change your opinion, not to change your recommendation to something that is different from your true opinion. People do make mistakes and do change their opinions about things in response to feedback. I’m not saying you *should* change your opinion, just that if you did, I wouldn’t see anything wrong with that.

   Now, if on the other hand the request is simply that you revise what you wrote to some specific recommendation regardless of what you actually believe, then such a request is blatantly unethical. Being a reviewer is a position of trust, and the whole refereeing system is built around the premise that editors, authors and readers can trust that referees are stating their true opinions rather than being influenced by irrelevant factors. Writing something that is not your opinion would be a betrayal of that trust, and undermines the entire system of academic publishing. I assume that such a betrayal is not something you would want to be a part of.

Comment: Thanks Dan, this was nearly identical the answer I would post. If the editor wants to allow revisions, they don't need the OP's permission, so for this to be straight up unethical pressure on peer review seems less likely than some sort of miscommunication. I wonder if the editor really just wants to know if the OP would be willing to review a round of changes that address their concerns and possibly accept a revised manuscript, given that they or the other reviewers see them as fixable rather than fatal flaws.

Comment: +1 especially for the first two points. There is likely some misunderstanding and a rash response would be ill-advised. However, I would add that there are situations where it is ethical for the editor to _insist_ on changes, such as the review being inappropriate and unprofessional (e.g. insulting the authors). I'm not saying that is the case here.

Comment: @Thomas Or even just not really to the standards of the journal...some journals do reject anything that isn't either essentially perfect or incredibly groundbreaking, others would typically give the authors a chance to revise unless their work is truly unsalvageable in the reviewers eyes. If a reviewer recommended rejection for, say, a missing control experiment that the authors could produce and salvage their paper I'd balk too if I was the editor.

Answer (score 11):

Ultimately, the decision is up to the editor and in this case they disagree with your assessment. This is not uncommon -- sometimes the reviewer is wrong or it could simply be that the reviewer has high standards and this is a low-quality journal. It sounds like the editor thinks the authors should be given an opportunity to address your concerns, which is reasonable.

*Is this normal?* Yes. The editor makes the final decision and often deviates from the reviews (indeed reviews are rarely unanimous, so deviation from some reviews is necessary). The editor wants to send the authors more consistent reviews, in order to minimize author complaints. And if your review seems excessively harsh, the editor may want that toned down to spare the authors' feelings (they are human too).

*Is this ethical?* To some extent it's just necessary. Some reviews do need to be fixed. If you feel that it is going too far and you are being asked to lie, rather than just change the tone, then you can push back and explain why you disagree. If you really feel that your input is being ignored, then refuse to review for that journal again.

*Any further thoughts?* Editors might even edit the reviews themselves without consulting the reviewers, since that might be quicker and easier. However, I think that is a bit inappropriate and disrespectful to the reviewer.

Comment: +1 This is close to what I was about to write. I think it's OK (barely) for the editor to ask you if you could lighten the tone, since the review will be sent to the author. I don't think it's right to ask you to change any conclusions. The editor is of course free to weigh the reviews any way s/he likes. That's the editor's job.

Comment: This isn't a case of simply lightening the tone of a review, they're asking the reviewer to retract their recommendation of rejection. Yes, editors are free to make a final decision irrespective of reviewer recommendations, but I have never heard of a reviewer being asked to change their assessment to be more in line with what the editor wants - this isn't normal. Peer review is supposed to be an unbiased assessment, exposing reviewers to other reviewers' comments or pressuring them to give a positive assessment flies in the face of that.

Comment: Changing reject to major revision is not a huge change. It’s really just a question of whether the authors should have a second chance to fix their manuscript. Although I do not know the exact situation it may simply be that OP is applying high standards and the journal in question  would have no papers if it applied those standards.

Comment: @Thomas To me, there's a *huge* difference between reject and major revisions. Major revisions means the paper can be fixed, maybe there's something missing or something is unclear, but the principle is sound. Flat-out rejection suggests something is more fundamentally wrong - the reviewer cannot even articulate a set of changes that would make the paper acceptable for publication. The OP gave 6 pages of comments, but evidently didn't feel that even addressing all of them would fix the underlying issues.

Comment: @NuclearWang You are presuming that OP has correctly decided that the paper is irredeemable and the editor and two other reviewers are wrong. People should be open to accepting that they may be wrong. My answer says `you can push back and explain why you disagree` but I don't think it's advisable to stubbornly refuse to reconsider.

Comment: @NuclearWang I think the fundamental disagreement between you and me is that I am interpreting the question as one where OP is potentially being too harsh. After all, the editor and two other reviewers feel that way. OP has written 6 pages and yet the editor has said the recommendation is "not good enough substantiated." What seems more likely: OP is being too harsh (perhaps because of inexperience) or everyone else is wrong?

Comment: _Is this ethical? To some extent it’s just necessary._ Hmm, interesting that you hesitate to use one of the words “yes” or “no”. It’s a simple question, and a good answer would answer it rather than equivocating. If you think it’s ethical, please say so.

Comment: @DanRomik It's a bit unclear what "this" is. It really depends on whether it's justified. My answer explains why it might be necessary and that there is a line where too much is being asked. I don't think a yes/no answer suffices.

Comment: @JeffE I don't understand your comment.

Comment: _I don’t think a yes/no answer suffices_ — Perhaps not, but the lack of a clear yes or no makes your answer unclear. You’ve replied to “Is this ethical?” with “Sometimes it’s necessary; sometimes it’s excessive”, but necessary/excessive and ethical/unethical are not the same things.

Answer (score 8):

> I have received a petition to change my verdict to major changes. The rationale is that the other two reviewers have given major changes and that my review is too harsh and not...substantiated.

A more precise understanding of the circumstances is necessary to answer your questions. I wonder whether the editor is trying to establish whether to outright reject or whether to offer major corrections. Since you're the only reviewer that recommends rejection, it is absolutely normal (and ethical) that the editor is consulting you. They want you to further help them in making their decision.

Comment: *A more precise understanding of the circumstances is necessary to answer your questions.* – Yet you arrive at an absolute assessment (“They want”) rather than an educated guess (“They may want”) at the end.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You're cherry picking. I open with _I wonder whether_, everything that follows should be considered in the context of that.

Comment: (Admittedly, I could have been more precise. But, precision takes time and I aim to maximise those I help, rather than crafting precise answers to all.)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I am assuming that the editor is explicitly primarily asking you to change your verdict, and not to reconsider specific rationales of your review in light of the other reviews or to phrase your review more friendly or to substantiate some of your claims.

If this is the case, then it indeed raises some red flags as it is completely unnecessary in a healthy situation:
All decision-making processes I know do not allow reviewers to decide a paper’s fate directly.
Instead the editor decides on base of the reviews or it is even the editor-in-chief who decides on basis of the editor’s recommendation, which in turn is based on the reviews.
Thus, if the editor wants a major revision, there is no need to change your verdict – in particular since this is the least surprising decision anyway, given two reviews recommending major revision and one recommending rejection.

This poses the question why the editor would like your verdict changed, and all I can think about is that they want to bypass some sort of quality control, for example:

- The decision is upon the editor-in-chief and the editor wishes to illegitimately improve the chances of the paper.
- The journal is one that publishes reviews, and the editor expects that accepting this paper given your current review could negatively affect them.
- The journal is rather competitive and has some strict unpublished rules that would force the editor to reject the paper with only one reject recommendation. In this case, it would be completely out of line for the editor to meddle like this. Of course, one may consider such rules harmful, but if that’s beyond your responsibility.

I would thus recommend to do the following:

- Double-check your interpretation of the mail.
- Consider asking the editor for clarification as to what they want.
- Look for further red flags, e.g., that the request was sent privately and not via the journal’s channels (does not apply to those journals that do not have a respective system).
- Escalate the situation to the editor-in-chief, publisher, or public (in that order if the previous escalations did not yield a satisfying outcome).

Comment: Another reason to add to your list: The editor may simply want the review changed because he or she thinks the harshness is unwarranted and does not wish to forward it to the authors as is. Academics are people too.

Comment: @Thomas: Please see the first paragraph.

Answer (score -3):

Given that journal editors are notorious for (almost surely) never changing *their* "reject" verdict (which is a policy originating in the long-held belief of *publishers* that writers of any sort are "immature" creatures even though talented, and so they are to be treated with strict authority to keep them in check), it is poetically unjust for editors to ask from reviewers to change *their* reject verdict.

Serving poetic justice alone demands from you to reject the editor's submitted request, let alone all the other aspects of the matter already analytically discussed in the answers here.

Answer (score -13):

Outright rejecting a paper denies authors the opportunity to correct issues raised by reviewers (and to publish at that venue). By comparison, major revisions afford such an opportunity. Authors might not be able to make the sufficient corrections, hence, reviewers may still reject. But, if they do make sufficient corrections, then the community benefits from the value added by reviewers. By comparison, no such value is guaranteed from an outright rejection, because authors may simply resubmit elsewhere without modification.

Perhaps the editor is trying to maximise community value.

Comment: I would think, if somebody writes six pages, they include enough details which allow for a major revision. If it was so bad that it should be rejected, six pages is a lot. I would think a reject decision would be like "We found three unacceptable and unsolvable issues" and six pages with detailed criticism would be constructive enough to create a revision.

Comment: Authors can still revise paper before submitting it to another journal. In fact they should.

Comment: @allo I can't see a relation to your comment and my answer, are you commenting on the OP's question?

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Indeed: They can and should, but there is no mechanism to ensure they do.

Comment: @user2768 The mechanism is caller peer-review. If the paper still contains errors, it will likely be rejected again.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov Are you claiming that no manuscript has been rejected by one venue only to be accepted (unmodified) by another?

Comment: No, outright rejection does _not_ deny such opportunity. Given the review, the authors can write a new paper. It seems like you argue that a complete replacement of the paper with something else could still count as just a "major revision"... -1.

Comment: This misses the point. Just because one reviewer recommends rejection, it doesn't mean the editor is obligated to do it. So if the editor is seeking to "maximise community value" there is no need for them to seek the reviewer's permission to do so.

Comment: @einpoklum How does it not?

Comment: @MJeffryes True, but that perhaps depends on policy.

Comment: I downvoted because the statement "Outright rejecting a paper denies authors the opportunity to correct issues raised by reviewers." is simply false. Even assuming the paper gets rejected as a final verdict by the editor, that is not an absolute order to throw the entirety of the paper away and never touch the topic again. Rejection denies nothing other than the publication of the manuscript in the target venue as a result of the manuscript's current submission process.

Comment: @user2768 I have never heard of a journal policy which requires that an editor rejects a manuscript if a single reviewer recommends it. This is why the reviewer verdict is called a recommendation.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's rather pedantic: I did think of phrasing my answer to exclude exactly that case, but, frankly, I thought it was obvious/unnecessary.

Comment: @MJeffryes I don't dispute. I haven't heard of such a policy either, but it seems perfectly conceivable and, given that the editor is pushing for a changed recommendation, it seems that such a policy could exist.

Comment: @user2768: I literally answered your question in my comment.

Comment: @einpoklum It seems you haven't understood my answer: Rejection denies the authors publication (at that venue), it also denies the authors the ability to have their revisions checked by those that made them. I'm unclear what "a complete replacement of the paper with something else could still count as just a 'major revision'" even means.

Comment: @user2768: Your last comment says something different than your answer. Indeed, the reviewer will not re-read the paper after the changes you have made, but that's not denying the opportunity to correct the paper. You'll just not get the same person to re-read it in the same context. While a second read would be convenient, that is definitely not something you are entitled to.

Comment: @einpoklum I see no difference between my comment and answer. (I do note that I didn't make _the same venue_ aspect explicit in my original answer, because I thought it was obvious, and I have edited in response to _O.R.Mapper_.) A major reject signifies an entitlement to a second read.

Comment: By the logic of this question, it's wrong for any paper to ever get rejected from anywhere! Additionally, it doesn't address the question asked and instead criticises the OP's original decision to reject, which is not the decision they're looking for help with now.

Comment: @Meelah Erm, no... Rejection is fine. I merely highlight reasons to recommend _major revision_ rather than _reject_.  I do not criticise the OP, in fact, I don't even mention the OP, I merely explain why the editor might want a _major revision_. In any case, the community doesn't seem to like my answer....

Comment: I am amazed at how this answer got bashed. This is indeed a point of view I hear a lot, and while I do not fully agree with it, I do not think it is some statement that should be somehow discouraged. I thought downvoting was meant for low-quality input and not for ideological manifestation!

Comment: Editors _always_ try to “maximise community value”. When they reject a paper outright it’s precisely to free up their and the referees’ time and the journal’s other resources to pursue higher quality papers, with the goal of best serving the journal’s readers and the scientific community. So I don’t see the point of the last sentence, nor of several other statements in this answer (like the opening sentence) that are technically correct but do little to address OP’s question.

Comment: @DanRomik It seems you're disagreeing with me, yet your argument supports me: Outright reject maximises value in the right cases and major corrections does to. I'm basically suggesting the editor is trying to maximise value.

Comment: I neither agree nor disagree with you, I just don’t see how any of what you wrote helps OP with any of the things they asked about. Also, as @Meelah said, your answer makes it sound like you generally oppose rejection of any paper under any circumstances, since you only state the benefits of giving the authors another chance to revise, but ignore the opportunity cost that goes along with that option. Now that you’ve clarified things I understand that your view is more balanced, but your answer needs to be rephrased if you don’t want people to misunderstand your position.

Comment: @DanRomik For the OP, I was just trying to explain the editor's position. Regarding Meelah, I didn't mention why papers should sometimes be rejected, because that seemed outside the OP's scope. Of course they should. I think I clarified that somewhere above.

Comment: *I merely explain why the editor might want a* major revision. – If the editor wants a major revision, the editor should just decide a major revision – which would even be the least surprising decision, with two reviews recommending major revision and one recommending rejection. However, it does not justify making one reviewer (the asker) change their review.

Comment: @user94036 Rejection only ever comes from the editor, never from the reviewer. So, _[from the editor]_ is implicitly included.